# What does "runs" mean?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Pilot Poe commands:

> Poe: Hit the target dead center. As many **runs** as we can get.

What does "runs" mean?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

He's referring to **bombing runs**. I.e. take as many passes as the target as possible to try and inflict as much damage as they can. Note that in this scene they are bombing the oscillator on Starkiller Base. This is made clear immediately after that they do a bombing run on the target. Poe then makes it even more explicit after the first bombing run:

> **Poe:** Yeah, we gotta keep hitting it! Another bombing run! Remember, when that sun is gone, that weapon will be ready to fire! But as long as there's light, we got a chance.
>
> <sub>*The Force Awakens*</sub>